# Bad scoring due to different maxDocs of IDF

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two documents with a field `title` of:

- News
- New Website

If I search for the term `new website` the score for the **News** document is **much** higher than the other one which is obviously not what I want. I wrapped an explain around it and got:

```json
'hits': [{'_explanation': {'desc': 'product of:',
   'det': [{'desc': 'sum of:',
    'det': [{'desc': 'product of:',
     'det': [{'desc': 'sum of:',
      'det': [{'desc': 'weight(title:new in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:',
       'det': [{'desc': 'score(doc=0,freq=1.0), product of:',
        'det': [{'desc': 'queryWeight, product of:',
         'det': [{'desc': 'idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=6)',
          'value': 2.0986123},
          {'desc': 'queryNorm',
           'value': 0.14544667}],
          'value': 0.3052362},
          {'desc': 'fieldWeight in 0, product of:',
           'det': [{'desc': 'tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:',
            'det': [{'desc': 'termFreq=1.0',
             'value': 1.0}],
            'value': 1.0},
            {'desc': 'idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=6)',
             'value': 2.0986123},
            {'desc': 'fieldNorm(doc=0)',
             'value': 0.625}],
            'value': 1.3116326}],
          'value': 0.40035775}],
       'value': 0.40035775}],
      'value': 0.40035775},
      {'desc': 'coord(1/2)',
       'value': 0.5}],
      'value': 0.20017888}],
    'value': 0.20017888},
    {'desc': 'coord(1/2)',
     'value': 0.5}],
    'value': 0.10008944},
    '_id': '2ff1307b536102e41e7daaccaf7edc69b16a348c',
    '_index': 'scrapy',
    '_node': 'D9SgrDb5RnO4NMAJMHiAOA',
    '_score': 0.100089446,
    '_shard': 3,
    '_source': {'title': ['\n       News ?  E/CIS\n    '],
     'url': 'http://178.4.12.128:8888/news/'},
    '_type': 'pages'},
    {'_explanation': {'desc': 'product of:',
     'det': [{'desc': 'sum of:',
      'det': [{'desc': 'sum of:',
       'det': [{'desc': 'weight(title:new in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:',
        'det': [{'desc': 'score(doc=0,freq=1.0), product of:',
         'det': [{'desc': 'queryWeight, product of:',
          'det': [{'desc': 'idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)',
           'value': 0.30685282},
           {'desc': 'queryNorm',
            'value': 0.46183997}],
           'value': 0.1417169},
           {'desc': 'fieldWeight in 0, product of:',
            'det': [{'desc': 'tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:',
             'det': [{'desc': 'termFreq=1.0',
              'value': 1.0}],
             'value': 1.0},
             {'desc': 'idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)',
              'value': 0.30685282},
             {'desc': 'fieldNorm(doc=0)',
              'value': 0.5}],
             'value': 0.15342641}],
           'value': 0.021743115}],
        'value': 0.021743115},
        {'desc': 'weight(title:websit in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:',
         'det': [{'desc': 'score(doc=0,freq=1.0), product of:',
          'det': [{'desc': 'queryWeight, product of:',
           'det': [{'desc': 'idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)',
            'value': 0.30685282},
            {'desc': 'queryNorm',
             'value': 0.46183997}],
            'value': 0.1417169},
            {'desc': 'fieldWeight in 0, product of:',
             'det': [{'desc': 'tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:',
              'det': [{'desc': 'termFreq=1.0',
               'value': 1.0}],
              'value': 1.0},
              {'desc': 'idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)',
               'value': 0.30685282},
              {'desc': 'fieldNorm(doc=0)',
               'value': 0.5}],
              'value': 0.15342641}],
            'value': 0.021743115}],
         'value': 0.021743115}],
        'value': 0.04348623}],
      'value': 0.04348623},
      {'desc': 'coord(1/2)',
       'value': 0.5}],
      'value': 0.021743115},
      '_id': '265988d175a2b4a2ae2e462509089d5f701ed372',
      '_index': 'scrapy',
      '_node': 'D9SgrDb5RnO4NMAJMHiAOA',
    '_score': 0.021743115,
                    '_shard': 0,
                    '_source': {'title': ['\n       New Website ?  E/CIS\n    '],
                      'url': 'http://178.4.12.128:8888/news/2015-new-website/'},
                    '_type': 'pages'}],
          'max_score': 0.100089446,
          'total': 2}
```

Note I shortened `details` to `det` and `description` to `desc` to save space.

It looks like the biggest difference is due to the difference of **maxDocs** in the scoring. Why do I have a difference there? I thought that this was the number of documents in the index? Shouldn't that be the same?

## More Details

Full details following but they might not be needed:

### Query

My query:

```json
 'multi_match': {
    'query': 'new website',
    'type': 'most_fields',
    'fields': ['title.raw^15', 'title^10'],
    'analyzer': 'whitespace_analyzer',
 }
```

### Mapping

```json
 'title': {
     'type': 'string',
     'store': 'yes',
     "index_analyzer": "nGram_analyzer",
     "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer",
     'fields': {
         'raw': {
             'type': 'string',
             'store': 'yes',
             "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer",
             "index": "not_analyzed",
         },
     }
 },
```

### Analyzer & Filter

```json
  'analysis': {
      "filter": {
          "nGram_filter": {
              "type": "nGram",
              "min_gram": 2,
              "max_gram": 20,
              "token_chars": [
                  "letter",
                  "digit",
                  "punctuation",
                  "symbol"
              ]
          },
          "english_stop": {
              "type":       "stop",
              "stopwords":  "_english_"
          },
          "english_stemmer": {
              "type":       "stemmer",
              "language":   "english"
          },
          "english_possessive_stemmer": {
              "type":       "stemmer",
              "language":   "possessive_english"
          }
      },
      "analyzer": {
          "html_analyzer": {
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "whitespace",
              "char_filter": ["html_strip"],
              "filter": [
                  'english_possessive_stemmer',
                  "lowercase",
                  'english_stop',
                  'english_stemmer',
                  "asciifolding",
              ]
          },
          "nGram_analyzer": {
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "whitespace",
              "char_filter": ["html_strip"], # Strips the html tags
              "filter": [
                  'english_possessive_stemmer',
                  "lowercase",
                  'english_stop',
                  'english_stemmer',
                  "asciifolding",
                  "nGram_filter"
              ]
          },
          "whitespace_analyzer": {
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "whitespace",
              "filter": [
                  'english_possessive_stemmer',
                  "lowercase",
                  'english_stop',
                  'english_stemmer',
                  "asciifolding",
              ]
          }
```

Comment: are you using [query_then/and_fetch or dfs_query_then/and_fetch](https://www.elastic.co/blog/understanding-query-then-fetch-vs-dfs-query-then-fetch)

Comment: Adding `search_type='dfs_query_then_fetch'` did solve my issue and I understand what's going on! Thank you very much. If you answer the question I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default search type  is [query_then_fetch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-type.html#query-then-fetch) . 
Both *query_then_fetch* and *query_and_fetch* involve calculating  the term and document frequency local to each of the shards in the index.

However if you want a more accurate calculation of term/document frequency  one can use *dfs_query_then_fetch/dfs_query_and_fetch* .Here the frequency is calculated across all the shards of indexes involved.

This [article](https://www.elastic.co/blog/understanding-query-then-fetch-vs-dfs-query-then-fetch) gives a more detailed explanation